# How can I set the speed of a symbol moving on a polyline

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-polyline

I'm creating a project for my internship, and I have some planes moving on a polyline in google maps. I want to create my project on the simple way because I have almost no experience, and maybe i'm making this the wrong way and that´s why i´m asking for help. [You can see what i'm talking about here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bABP8.png)

I Have 4 planes in the moment so I had to create one function to each one because if i don´´t the Plane to Spain arrives at the same time than the plane to Brasil, and they both took off at the same time.

This is what I have in the moment, so I created the costum path symbol and then the polylines.

```js
function initMap() {
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
        zoom: 3,
        center: {lat: 12.1336018, lng: -15.1832411},
        mapTypeId: 'terrain'
    });
    //Define the custom symbols. All symbols are defined via SVG path notation.
    // They have varying stroke color, fill color, stroke weight,
    // opacity and rotation properties.

    var planeSymbol = {path: 'M 8.1326447,0.80527736 C 8.5471666,0.063577346 9.742752,0.030177346 10.052431,0.82497736 C 10.093464,3.0114774 10.134497,5.1980774 10.17553,7.3845774 C 12.760407,8.9653774 15.345284,10.546179 17.930161,12.127079 C 17.930161,12.881779 17.930161,13.636479 17.930161,14.391179 C 15.373077,13.579479 12.815993,12.767779 10.258908,11.956179 C 10.27281,13.280479 10.286713,14.604879 10.300615,15.929279 C 10.8565,16.555879 11.412385,17.182479 11.96827,17.809079 C 12.25527,18.269479 12.437605,19.641079 11.59784,19.085079 C 10.804104,18.802179 10.010367,18.519179 9.21663,18.236279 C 8.3133108,18.620779 7.4099916,19.005279 6.5066724,19.389779 C 6.3952441,18.705879 6.2272708,17.857479 6.8519879,17.359679 C 7.2927717,16.882879 7.7335555,16.406079 8.1743393,15.929279 C 8.1465467,14.604879 8.1187541,13.280479 8.0909615,11.956179 C 5.5894706,12.824879 3.0879797,13.693479 0.58648883,14.562179 C 0.54479393,13.821679 0.50309893,13.081079 0.46140403,12.340579 C 3.0184842,10.717079 5.5755645,9.0935778 8.1326447,7.4700774 C 8.1326447,5.2484774 8.1326447,3.0268774 8.1326447,0.80527736 z',
        scale: 1,
        strokeOpacity: 1,
        strokecolor: 'black',
        strokeWeight: 1,
        anchor: new google.maps.Point(9, 9)
    };


    var GRU = new google.maps.Polyline({
        path: [{lat: 38.771183, lng: -9.131135}, {lat: -23.6276104, lng: -46.6568016}], //Lis - GRU
        strokeOpacity: 0.1,
        icons: [{
                icon: planeSymbol,
                offset: '0'
            }],
        map: map});
    animatePlane(GRU);

    var LAD = new google.maps.Polyline({
        path: [{lat: 38.771183, lng: -9.131135}, {lat: -8.8648774, lng: 13.2249472}], //Lis - LAD
        strokeOpacity: 0.1,
        icons: [{
                icon: planeSymbol,
                offset: '0'
            }],
        map: map});
    animatePlane1(LAD);

    var MIA = new google.maps.Polyline({
        path: [{lat: 38.771183, lng: -9.131135}, {lat: 25.8027373, lng: -80.2892127}], //Lis - MIA
        strokeOpacity: 0.1,
        icons: [{
                icon: planeSymbol,
                offset: '0'
            }],
        map: map});
    animatePlane2(MIA);

    var MAD = new google.maps.Polyline({
        path: [{lat: 38.771183, lng: -9.131135}, {lat: 40.4690627, lng: -3.5599042}], //Lis - MAD
        strokeOpacity: 0.1,
        icons: [{
                icon: planeSymbol,
                offset: '0'
            }],
        map: map});
    animatePlane3(MAD);
    
    
    

    function animatePlane(line) {
        var count = 0;
        var listener = window.setInterval(function() {
            count = (count + 1) % 200;

            var icons = line.get('icons');
            icons[0].offset = (count / 2) + '%';
            line.set('icons', icons);
            if (count >= 199)
                clearInterval(listener);
        }, 2000);
    }

    function animatePlane1(line) {
        var count = 0;
        var listener = window.setInterval(function() {
            count = (count + 1) % 200;

            var icons = line.get('icons');
            icons[0].offset = (count / 2) + '%';
            line.set('icons', icons);
            if (count >= 199)
                clearInterval(listener);
        }, 2000);
    }
    
        function animatePlane2(line) {
        var count = 0;
        var listener = window.setInterval(function() {
            count = (count + 1) % 200;

            var icons = line.get('icons');
            icons[0].offset = (count / 2) + '%';
            line.set('icons', icons);
            if (count >= 199)
                clearInterval(listener);
        }, 2000);
    }

    function animatePlane3(line) {
        var count = 0;
        var listener = window.setInterval(function() {
            count = (count + 1) % 200;

            var icons = line.get('icons');
            icons[0].offset = (count / 2) + '%';
            line.set('icons', icons);
            if (count >= 199)
                clearInterval(listener);
        }, 2000);
    }

}
```

```css
#map {
    width: 900px;
    height: 684px;

}
```

```html
<html>
    <body>     
<div id="map"></div>  
        
      
      <script async defer src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyCUYsLGs_ek6Ids4TN1ZZeJvv6X-r4j5N4&callback=initMap"></script>
                    
    </body>
</html>
```

So this is just a sample but my real question is can I simulate the real speed of the plane or can i set how many time(in hours) it takes to a plane to reach the end of a polyline?

*Pls don´t report my question, just help me learning! if i'm off topic just tell me how to improve my questions :D*

Comment: increase the set Interval time from 20 to 2000

Comment: thx for your answer :D, I did and it keeps happening that the plane to Madrid arrives at the same time than the other ones, I had to set the count +0.1 in all of them or the plane would me moving really fast and it is not smooth as it was with the interval time 20

Comment: u can use stack overflow code snipt for code.. so i can check

Comment: done, you can check!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, first let's get rid of those four functions.  One function can handle all.

Since it's a generic function now, we need parameters to specify what we're handling.

As parameters I chose steps (= number of steps), and stepTime ( number of milliseconds between steps).  I could have chosen different parameters, like speed and totalTime, but that's just simple calculations.

Anyway, as an example I set 20 steps to Madrid, stepTime 2 seconds, so you get there in 40 seconds.

Can you handle the calculations?  Or do you need anything specific?  Search the distance, guestimate the ideal step time, ... Deepak's answer gives you a distance calculator, and a way of thinking about it...

Anyway, let me know

```
<script>
// http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42225019/how-can-i-set-the-speed-of-a-symbol-moving-on-a-polyline#42225019
function initMap() {

var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    zoom: 3,
    center: {lat: 12.1336018, lng: -15.1832411},
    mapTypeId: 'terrain'
});
//Define the custom symbols. All symbols are defined via SVG path notation.
// They have varying stroke color, fill color, stroke weight,
// opacity and rotation properties.
var planeSymbol = {path: 'M 8.1326447,0.80527736 C 8.5471666,0.063577346 9.742752,0.030177346 10.052431,0.82497736 C 10.093464,3.0114774 10.134497,5.1980774 10.17553,7.3845774 C 12.760407,8.9653774 15.345284,10.546179 17.930161,12.127079 C 17.930161,12.881779 17.930161,13.636479 17.930161,14.391179 C 15.373077,13.579479 12.815993,12.767779 10.258908,11.956179 C 10.27281,13.280479 10.286713,14.604879 10.300615,15.929279 C 10.8565,16.555879 11.412385,17.182479 11.96827,17.809079 C 12.25527,18.269479 12.437605,19.641079 11.59784,19.085079 C 10.804104,18.802179 10.010367,18.519179 9.21663,18.236279 C 8.3133108,18.620779 7.4099916,19.005279 6.5066724,19.389779 C 6.3952441,18.705879 6.2272708,17.857479 6.8519879,17.359679 C 7.2927717,16.882879 7.7335555,16.406079 8.1743393,15.929279 C 8.1465467,14.604879 8.1187541,13.280479 8.0909615,11.956179 C 5.5894706,12.824879 3.0879797,13.693479 0.58648883,14.562179 C 0.54479393,13.821679 0.50309893,13.081079 0.46140403,12.340579 C 3.0184842,10.717079 5.5755645,9.0935778 8.1326447,7.4700774 C 8.1326447,5.2484774 8.1326447,3.0268774 8.1326447,0.80527736 z',
    scale: 1,
    strokeOpacity: 1,
    strokecolor: 'black',
    strokeWeight: 1,
    anchor: new google.maps.Point(9, 9)
};

var GRU = new google.maps.Polyline({
    path: [{lat: 38.771183, lng: -9.131135}, {lat: -23.6276104, lng: -46.6568016}], //Lis - GRU
    strokeOpacity: 0.1,
    icons: [{
            icon: planeSymbol,
            offset: '0'
        }],
    map: map});
var LAD = new google.maps.Polyline({
    path: [{lat: 38.771183, lng: -9.131135}, {lat: -8.8648774, lng: 13.2249472}], //Lis - LAD
    strokeOpacity: 0.1,
    icons: [{
            icon: planeSymbol,
            offset: '0'
        }],
    map: map});
var MIA = new google.maps.Polyline({
    path: [{lat: 38.771183, lng: -9.131135}, {lat: 25.8027373, lng: -80.2892127}], //Lis - MIA
    strokeOpacity: 0.1,
    icons: [{
            icon: planeSymbol,
            offset: '0'
        }],
    map: map});
var MAD = new google.maps.Polyline({
    path: [{lat: 38.771183, lng: -9.131135}, {lat: 40.4690627, lng: -3.5599042}], //Lis - MAD
    strokeOpacity: 0.1,
    icons: [{
            icon: planeSymbol,
            offset: '0'
        }],
    map: map});
// call the function for all flight paths
animatePlaneLine(GRU, 100, 200);  // 100 steps at an interval of 0.2 seconds 
animatePlaneLine(LAD, 200, 2000);
animatePlaneLine(MIA, 200, 2000);
animatePlaneLine(MAD, 20, 2000);   // 20 steps, at an interval of 2 seconds 

// One function to rule them all      
function animatePlaneLine(line, steps, stepTime) {
  var count = 0;  // it counts from 0 to (parameter) steps, then cycles.
  var listener = window.setInterval(function() {
    count = (count + 1) % steps;
    var icons = line.get('icons');
    icons[0].offset = (100 * count / steps) + '%';
    line.set('icons', icons);
  }, stepTime);
  // you don't need this return, but you could use it for extra control, like if you have buttons to pause/stop/start the animation.
  return listener;  
}
}
</script>
```

Comment: wow, this is amazing! I'll do some research and then i will let you know! Thanks a lot!!! :)

Comment: I tried it with steps and i calculated this: an airplane travels 900km/h, so 900km = 900000 m, 1h = 3600s so 900000/3600 = 250 m. Then 1km has more a less 1250 steps so 1250 / 4 = 312.5 steps per second. And i changed all flight paths and they are not traveling 312.5 steps per second because they are are reaching the destination all on the same time again, so I think the best is calculate by the distance. Thx a lot!

Comment: Yes, glad to help.

Comment: can´t find anything, do you know how can I do it?

Answer (score 1):

So you have animate markers on a custom speed. this can be easily done by setting interval of setinterval. but the main task is how to set a specific interval.

you can build a logic.

getthe distance between 2 points. basically 2 lat longs.

```
function getDistanceFromLatLonInKm(lat1,lon1,lat2,lon2) {
  var R = 6371; // Radius of the earth in km
  var dLat = deg2rad(lat2-lat1);  // deg2rad below
  var dLon = deg2rad(lon2-lon1); 
  var a = 
    Math.sin(dLat/2) * Math.sin(dLat/2) +
    Math.cos(deg2rad(lat1)) * Math.cos(deg2rad(lat2)) * 
    Math.sin(dLon/2) * Math.sin(dLon/2)
    ; 
  var c = 2 * Math.atan2(Math.sqrt(a), Math.sqrt(1-a)); 
  var d = R * c; // Distance in km
  return d;
}

function deg2rad(deg) {
  return deg * (Math.PI/180)
}
```

now lets distance is 1000 KM

the avrage speed of plane in air is 217.76 km/h

so you will reach 4000 km in 4 hours, so you have to set your interval as 14440

I know its very slow. but its actual simulation of your plane.

You can display remaining time based on this time in your HTML page.

Hope you can write logic for it. its easy!!

Comment: Ah, you consider the earth to be a perfect sphere.  I guess it shouldn't make much difference for flightpaths.

Comment: thx a lot buddy! so i need to change the path symbol to markers right?